# Get all files uploaded using Meteor-Files

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I would like to get all files that were uploaded using `Meteor-Files`.

To do so I've uploaded one file successfully and tried using `find`. This doesn't return a list but instead an object.

**Client**

`UnprocessedFilesCollection.collection.find({})`

**Response - 1 File uploaded**

```
{
  "collection": {
    "name": "UnprocessedFiles",
    "_docs": {
      "_map": {
        "k2fe6eqs3XdkTbo6z": {
          "_id": "k2fe6eqs3XdkTbo6z",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\k2fe6eqs3XdkTbo6z.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\k2fe6eqs3XdkTbo6z.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "CnRLBgxxwQnjkXYyD": {
          "_id": "CnRLBgxxwQnjkXYyD",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\CnRLBgxxwQnjkXYyD.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\CnRLBgxxwQnjkXYyD.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "whWq5edhbkaJxZpcq": {
          "_id": "whWq5edhbkaJxZpcq",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\whWq5edhbkaJxZpcq.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\whWq5edhbkaJxZpcq.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "KoScr7mPzKQ3GZNfy": {
          "_id": "KoScr7mPzKQ3GZNfy",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\KoScr7mPzKQ3GZNfy.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\KoScr7mPzKQ3GZNfy.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "pvLvrS2YffDW3qMeZ": {
          "_id": "pvLvrS2YffDW3qMeZ",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\pvLvrS2YffDW3qMeZ.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\pvLvrS2YffDW3qMeZ.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "J2oLFJNsnEmwCL8RF": {
          "_id": "J2oLFJNsnEmwCL8RF",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\J2oLFJNsnEmwCL8RF.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\J2oLFJNsnEmwCL8RF.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "FyWqtF7dXk3spH75o": {
          "_id": "FyWqtF7dXk3spH75o",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\FyWqtF7dXk3spH75o.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\FyWqtF7dXk3spH75o.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "JiS9z3HgqzhhSXjyN": {
          "_id": "JiS9z3HgqzhhSXjyN",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\JiS9z3HgqzhhSXjyN.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\JiS9z3HgqzhhSXjyN.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "XXhA3ynYRhXeqTtM3": {
          "_id": "XXhA3ynYRhXeqTtM3",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\XXhA3ynYRhXeqTtM3.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\XXhA3ynYRhXeqTtM3.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "NKtMKseuKbZ3o4ZA3": {
          "_id": "NKtMKseuKbZ3o4ZA3",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\NKtMKseuKbZ3o4ZA3.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\NKtMKseuKbZ3o4ZA3.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "XfQsRGnAaztH4YPkZ": {
          "_id": "XfQsRGnAaztH4YPkZ",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\XfQsRGnAaztH4YPkZ.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\XfQsRGnAaztH4YPkZ.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "yi6TqhmMrvaCjFMxm": {
          "_id": "yi6TqhmMrvaCjFMxm",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\yi6TqhmMrvaCjFMxm.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\yi6TqhmMrvaCjFMxm.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "JrpZamJeaTG73Hn3w": {
          "_id": "JrpZamJeaTG73Hn3w",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\JrpZamJeaTG73Hn3w.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\JrpZamJeaTG73Hn3w.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "MSshj8ffzGfB7tb5A": {
          "_id": "MSshj8ffzGfB7tb5A",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\MSshj8ffzGfB7tb5A.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\MSshj8ffzGfB7tb5A.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "YNvL3NF56BoT9tk9P": {
          "_id": "YNvL3NF56BoT9tk9P",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\YNvL3NF56BoT9tk9P.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\YNvL3NF56BoT9tk9P.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "i6wAeJss6PX2c7Byc": {
          "_id": "i6wAeJss6PX2c7Byc",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\i6wAeJss6PX2c7Byc.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\i6wAeJss6PX2c7Byc.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "MWH8J2zxKopiu2ycs": {
          "_id": "MWH8J2zxKopiu2ycs",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\MWH8J2zxKopiu2ycs.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\MWH8J2zxKopiu2ycs.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "cwGzwrqyWcypuTmpB": {
          "_id": "cwGzwrqyWcypuTmpB",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\cwGzwrqyWcypuTmpB.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\cwGzwrqyWcypuTmpB.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "g4rNH3hTiMrLXEiNu": {
          "_id": "g4rNH3hTiMrLXEiNu",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test (1).csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\g4rNH3hTiMrLXEiNu.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\g4rNH3hTiMrLXEiNu.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "hyT4XcJKCQ6Z8sQA5": {
          "_id": "hyT4XcJKCQ6Z8sQA5",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\hyT4XcJKCQ6Z8sQA5.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\hyT4XcJKCQ6Z8sQA5.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "5CHrbGhZbMyutASFM": {
          "_id": "5CHrbGhZbMyutASFM",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\5CHrbGhZbMyutASFM.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\5CHrbGhZbMyutASFM.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "WZxYGtx6ZkYALgu3F": {
          "_id": "WZxYGtx6ZkYALgu3F",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test.csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\WZxYGtx6ZkYALgu3F.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\WZxYGtx6ZkYALgu3F.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        },
        "4eC4zivmKn4nH8kfT": {
          "_id": "4eC4zivmKn4nH8kfT",
          "size": 127,
          "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "name": "test (1).csv",
          "meta": {},
          "ext": "csv",
          "extension": "csv",
          "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
          "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
          "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
          "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\4eC4zivmKn4nH8kfT.csv",
          "versions": {
            "original": {
              "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\4eC4zivmKn4nH8kfT.csv",
              "size": 127,
              "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
              "extension": "csv"
            }
          },
          "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
          "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
          "isVideo": false,
          "isAudio": false,
          "isImage": false,
          "isText": false,
          "isJSON": false,
          "isPDF": false,
          "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
          "public": false
        }
      }
    },
    "_observeQueue": {
      "_tasks": [],
      "_running": false,
      "_runTimeout": null
    },
    "next_qid": 1,
    "queries": {},
    "_savedOriginals": null,
    "paused": false
  },
  "sorter": null,
  "matcher": {
    "_paths": {},
    "_hasGeoQuery": false,
    "_hasWhere": false,
    "_isSimple": true,
    "_selector": {}
  },
  "skip": 0,
  "_transform": null,
  "reactive": true
}
```

I was expecting the response to be an array of uploaded files but it seems to be an object containing multiple entries in a map per file.

**Using `toArray()` throws an exception as the function is undefined**
`UnprocessedFilesCollection.collection.find({}).toArray()`

What is the correct method of retrieving the files?

**Update**

I noticed I was missing `.cursor` after the `find()`. The response still isn't as I would expect.

```
import { FilesCollection } from 'meteor/ostrio:files';

export const UnprocessedFilesCollection = new FilesCollection({
  collectionName: 'UnprocessedFiles',
  allowClientCode: true, // Required to let you remove uploaded file
  onBeforeUpload(file) {
    // Allow upload files under 10MB, and only in png/jpg/jpeg formats
    if (file.size <= 10485760 && /csv|png|jpg|jpeg/i.test(file.ext)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return 'Please upload image, with size equal or less than 10MB';
    }
  }
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('files.images.all');
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('files.images.all', () => {
    return UnprocessedFilesCollection.find().cursor;
  });
}
```

**Client**

`UnprocessedFilesCollection.find();`

**Response**

```
{
  "size": 127,
  "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
  "name": "test.csv",
  "meta": {},
  "ext": "csv",
  "extension": "csv",
  "extensionWithDot": ".csv",
  "mime": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
  "mime-type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
  "_id": "C2X9vPvFyu5aGi8jq",
  "userId": "LFfySMkYjYkCqB3zQ",
  "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\C2X9vPvFyu5aGi8jq.csv",
  "versions": {
    "original": {
      "path": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles\\C2X9vPvFyu5aGi8jq.csv",
      "size": 127,
      "type": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
      "extension": "csv"
    }
  },
  "_downloadRoute": "/cdn/storage",
  "_collectionName": "UnprocessedFiles",
  "isVideo": false,
  "isAudio": false,
  "isImage": false,
  "isText": false,
  "isJSON": false,
  "isPDF": false,
  "_storagePath": "assets\\app\\uploads\\UnprocessedFiles",
  "public": false
}
```

Comment: Have you tried appending `.toArray` to the end of the find query?

Comment: I've tried using `toArray`/`toArray()` and the functions are undefined. I've updated the question.

Comment: Why Not Just using the FilesCollection? It should return the Cursor.

Comment: I've updated my question. I've made it use the collection directly but the response still isn't as I would expect.